# Simple Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a two tables: Interfaces and ConnectionStrings.  There is a many to many relationship between the tables and I normalized this by adding a 3rd table called InterfaceConnectionStrings.  I can query the table as follows via stored procedure to get the data I need:

```
Select I.InterfaceName as IName
,CS.ConnectionStringDescription as Descr
,CS.ConnectionStringValue as Value
from ConnectionStrings CS
JOIN InterfaceConnectionStrings ICS
on CS.ConnectionStringDescription = ICS.ConnectionStringDescription
JOIN Interfaces I
on ICS.InterfaceName = I.InterfaceName
where InterfaceName = @InterfaceName
```

A result will look like the following:

```
**IName**       **Descr**     **Value**
InterfaceX      CSDescr1      CS1Value
InterfaceX      CSDescr2      CS2Value
InterfaceX      CSDescr3      CS3Value
```

I would like to find a query that will return the following:

```
**IName**       **CSDescr1**     **CSDescr2**  **CSDescr3**
InterfaceX      CS1Value         CS2Value      CS3Value
```

I tried using PIVOT but have not made much progress.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Select InterfaceName as IName
,ConnectionStringDescription as Descr
,ConnectionStringValue as Value
From (
Select I.InterfaceName 
,CS.ConnectionStringDescription
,CS.ConnectionStringValue
 from ConnectionStrings CS
JOIN InterfaceConnectionStrings ICS
on CS.ConnectionStringDescription = ICS.ConnectionStringDescription
JOIN Interfaces I
on ICS.InterfaceName = I.InterfaceName) PvtBase

PIVOT

( MAX(PvtBase.Value) FOR
PvtBase.Descr IN PvtBase.Value) as Pvt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex:

```
declare @table table (iName varchar(25), Descr varchar(25), Value varchar(25))

insert into @table
select 'InterfaceX','CSDescr1','CS1Value' UNION ALL
select 'InterfaceX','CSDescr2','CS2Value' UNION ALL
select 'InterfaceX','CSDescr3','CS3Value'

select *
from (select * from @table) sub
pivot (max(value) for descr in ([CSDescr1],[CSDescr2],[CSDescr3])) p
```

For you, just replace `SELECT * FROM @TABLE` with your initial query (add add some aliases).

```
select *
from ( Select I.InterfaceName as iName
             ,CS.ConnectionStringDescription as descr
             ,CS.ConnectionStringValue as value
             from ConnectionStrings CS 
             JOIN InterfaceConnectionStrings ICS
                on CS.ConnectionStringDescription = ICS.ConnectionStringDescription
             JOIN Interfaces I
                on ICS.InterfaceName = I.InterfaceName
             where InterfaceName = @InterfaceName) sub
pivot (max(value) for descr in ([CSDescr1],[CSDescr2],[CSDescr3])) p
```

Comment: This is returning null in the value column

Comment: It will if there is no CSDescr1/2/3 for that Interface name in the sub-query.  That is normal for PIVOT.

Comment: Figured it out - this works!  Plus one even though I selected the other answer.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        Select  I.InterfaceName                 as IName
               ,CS.ConnectionStringDescription  as Descr
               ,CS.ConnectionStringValue        as Value
        from ConnectionStrings CS
        JOIN InterfaceConnectionStrings ICS
        on CS.ConnectionStringDescription = ICS.ConnectionStringDescription
        JOIN Interfaces I
        on ICS.InterfaceName = I.InterfaceName
        where InterfaceName = @InterfaceName
     ) t
PIVOT (MAX(Value)
       FOR Descr
       IN ([CSDescr1],[CSDescr2],[CSDescr3])
      )p
```

Comment: I'm getting nulls in the value column but "t" query returns data in the value col.

Comment: Okay - I had to modify the in statement to the true value of the descr data.  Works well - thanks!  I just have to get my head around the PIVOT syntax.